# Want to get the preceding-sibling

Tags: xslt

I  am parsing the XML like below,

```
<Service>
 <ServiceName>
 <Plans>
 <Plan>
    <PlanNumber>A</PlanNumber>
    ....
  </Plan>
 </Plans>
</Service>

<Service>
<ServieName>
 <Plans>
 <Plan>
    <PlanNumber>B</PlanNumber>
    ....
  </Plan>
 </Plans>
</Service>
```

I am iterating through `for-each Plans/Plan` and trying to  print `preceding-sibling::Plan/PlanNumber`, I am not getting anything.

I want this to iterate through the unique plan number so I am using an if statement next to the for-each. `<xsl-if test="not(PlanNumber = preceding-sibling::Plan/PlanNumber)">`

I am not getting through the PlanNumbers.

Comment: It's hard for me, at least, to understand what you want. Can you expand your code sample to include some of the elements that you mention in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627997/want-to-get-the-preceding-sibling#comment96077874_54635130? Can you add a mock-up graphic of what you want to achieve?  What XSLT version are you using?  It probably won't matter much, but what XSL formatter are you using?

Comment: Getting the preceding sibling is one thing; getting unique values is another. The method to accomplish the latter depends on whether your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is only one `Plan` in `Plans` (and only one `Plans` in `Service`). This means that `Plan` has no siblings and your attempt `preceding-sibling::Plan/PlanNumber` selects nothing.

To get the preceding `PlanNumber` from the context of `Plan`, you need to do:

```
../../preceding-sibling::Service/Plans/Plan/PlanNumber
```

or:

```
preceding::PlanNumber
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:foreach select="Plan">
    <xsl:foreach select="PlanNumber">
        <xsl:if test="position()!=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::text()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:foreach>
</xsl:foreach>
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to create a table where the table header row should present the distinct plan# spanning across columns.  Each plan may contain other elements like area and  discounts. so the discounts should be the column and plan number should be the header for the columns.   If have a plan number with 2 different area like Chn and Blr and discounts for each area, then I have to print a table with 2 columns, for Chn and Blr with discounts and the headers for these columns should be plan number A. In this case, I have to iterate through unique plan and get the count, span the columns.